# how to get a value from function

Tags: swift

i have a function that check if the value that the user entered is nil or not (spouse to be double). all the vars are declare inside the function.
now, I'm trying to get the var from the function and use it in my other code (outside the function). i tried to do it with return option but its show me an error. 
i look for it in google and as i see there I'm not sure if i can actually do it. 
does anyone have an idea how can i solve it?
here is my code:

```
func numbers() -> Double  {
print("enter plate heigh")
let num1 = Double(readLine()!)

if checkIfNil(value1: num1){
    print("plaese enter valid heigh")
    numbers()
}
else{
    let x = num1
    print("good! \(num1)")
    return x!
}
return 0.0
}

let platHeigh = numbers()
print("is: \(platHeigh)")
```

tnx!

Comment: how exactly did u use return statement pls share snippet

Comment: i said that i tried but not succeed so i erase it.

Comment: How do you expect people to help you fix what didn't work if you don't show what you did that didn't work?

Comment: I accidentally attached an old code...

Comment: the problem is that when i ran the code and just type return the checkifnil is running, but if after that i entered a number i the return is 0.0 and not the entered number. if on the first time i entered a number its working fine

Comment: Sounds like you want to loop while the input is invalid, rather than returning 0.0.

Comment: but i have to return some value at the end of the function. if i delete the return statement i get an error

Comment: I didn't say to not return, I said to only return once the input is determined to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your posted code is the fact that you don't make use of the result of calling `numbers()` inside your `numbers` function. You also have problems with force-unwrapping nil values which will causes crashes.

**Note:** Don't run this in the playground. Only use this in a command-line app.

It should be (ignoring the force-unwrapping issues for now):

```
func numbers() -> Double  {
    print("enter plate heigh")
    let num1 = Double(readLine()!)

    if checkIfNil(value1: num1){
        print("plaese enter valid heigh")
        return numbers() // you need to return here
    }
    else{
        let x = num1
        print("good! \(num1)")
        return x!
    }
}
```

But recursion isn't really a good solution for something like this. Use a simple loop.

```
func numbers() -> Double  {
    while true {
        print("enter plate height:")
        if let text = readLine() {
            if let num = Double(text) {
                print("good! \(num)")
                return num
            } else {
                print("Invalid number: \(text)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain me why i have to do "return numbers()" in the first example?

Comment: Because you want to return the value of calling the `numbers` function. Your code was ignoring the value it obtained and fell to the bottom just to return 0.

Comment: so if i do this, i can delete the last return statement ("return 0.0")? also, if i do this how can i be sure its not return a nil?

Comment: Try it. It can't return nil because you just keep calling `numbers` until it doesn't.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand. when i do "return numbers()" its not return a value? it just calling the fund again? just like "numbers()"

Comment: Yes, it returns the result of calling your `numbers` function. You need to understand what recursion is to understand what it happening when you call a function inside of itself. It's far too broad of a topic to cover in a comment.

Comment: tnx! it working. can u explain why you think the second way is better?

Comment: Because a loop is simpler than recursion.

Answer (score -1):

In this line:

```
let num1 = Double(readLine()!)
```

there will be already a crash, if `readLine()` returns nil. Because you are force unwrapping it using the `!`.

A better way is to use the [`if let` statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

```
var input: Double? = nil

func numbers() -> Double? {
    if let num1 = input {
        print("good! \(num1)")
        return num1
    } else {
        print("plaese enter valid heigh")
        return nil
    }
}
```

In this function num1 is assigned the value from your field only **if it is not nil**. Then it is returned.

Otherwise an error message is printed and nil is return. Outside of your function you now know, that nothing was entered.